# How to initialize from setstate in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

[image: I am able to initialize setstate still the values are taking from state only]

```
_handleClickFilter(value, xname, chartId){
    console.log("dataSourceId", this.state.dataSource);
    this.setState({
          filterData: [{
          filter: "equals",  
          value:value ,
          attribute:xname, 
        }]
        });

    let filterdefinitions = {
        dataSourceId : "59ef50d6e4b054efd6d8aa53",
        filterDefinitions: this.state.filterData,
      }

      let data = {
        filterDefinitions: [filterdefinitions],
      };
      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);
      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToChart(data, this.props.params.dashboardId, chartId);
      DashboardAction._saveFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);


}
```

I am able to get values in the setstate which I want. But the values are not getting set. Showing the values exists in the this.state only.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your component mounted, be carefull about that react is stateful

Comment: Try removing the extra comma to the key filterDefinitions in the object filterdefinitions

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ. Ya component mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is **async**, so it's not guaranteed that the state will be set after you have used it until the re-render is triggered. You should be very careful about using the state right after you have set it, a more 'reactive' approach is usually better. However, if you want to make sure that you'll be able to access the new state, you can use the **second argument of setState** which is a callback function that will be called when the state is set.

You can use it this way:

```
_handleClickFilter(value, xname, chartId){
    this.setState({
          filterData: [{
          filter: "equals",  
          value:value ,
          attribute:xname, 
        }]
    }, () => {

    let filterdefinitions = {
        dataSourceId : "59ef50d6e4b054efd6d8aa53",
        filterDefinitions: this.state.filterData,
      }

      let data = {
        filterDefinitions: [filterdefinitions],
      };
      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);
      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToChart(data, this.props.params.dashboardId, chartId);
      DashboardAction._saveFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your set state code with this

```
   this.setState({ 
        filterData: this.state.filterData.map((data, index) => {
        data.filter = "equals",
        data.value = value,
        data.attribute=xname
}) });
```